# How to scroll down programmatically in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui

Is there any way to scroll down programmatically with a tab to Group Header?

Please Check [{N} Playground example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=rqK7wO&v=15)

Comment: I don't think you can have a floating header, the component is not designed for that. If you just want to programatically scroll, you should try [scrollToVerticalOffset(...)](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview#scrolltoverticaloffset) You must know to which point you want to scroll to, you may calculate it by using [getLocationRelativeTo(...)](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview#getlocationrelativeto)

Comment: Is there any  `scrollToVertical` usage example playground in nativescript-vue_?